# Xcode sandboxed app "file not found" when the file is clearly there

Tags: swift, file, directory

I am trying to access a file from my app, which I have added to the root folder of the sandbox Container :

```swift
func getData() throws -> Data {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "~/test.dat")
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    return data
}
```

Yet when I try to use this function I get this error :

```swift
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “test.dat” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/crysambrosia/Library/Containers/C62869A9-4B70-4E37-8214-47A4E1A1AB38/Data/~/test.dat, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000333b990 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Yet I have added the file to that directory ! I have no idea what to do now, do I have to somehow give permission to my app to open that file ? But wouldn't the error be different if that was the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this didn't work is that the tilde `~` doesn't auto-expand, so you have to do this :

```swift
let url = URL(
    fileURLWithPath: ("~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/New World/level.dat" as NSString)
        .expandingTildeInPath
)
```

( or a more elegant spelling of the same )